# Unable to implement FullCalendar into ASP.NET MVC4 application getting: 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: fullcalendar

Unable to implement FullCalendar into ASP.NET MVC4 application getting: 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

I got the code from the website but am getting the above error. Here is the code:

```
{
  ViewBag.Title = "Calendar";
} 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='Content/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>




<h2>Calendar</h2>
<div id="calendar" style="width:65%"></div>
<script  type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

 });
</script>
```

All of the files exist as I installed the NuGet packages.

Comment: have you looked at the line where the error is occurring? Where does it happen? You might get a friendlier error message from Chrome - that looks like IE's crummy error reporting. The most likely problem though is that you aren't referencing the various JS files properly. Check that they a) exist, and b) exist in the place you think they do. The network tab of your browser dev tools might also tell you if any of the files are failing to load when the page runs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have been working with IE for this and the server I was developing on did not have Chrome, so I installed it and it just worked. Probably should have tried that beforehand, but many thanks nonetheless!

Comment: is it still broken in IE, though? What version of IE is it?

Comment: Well it's the default version of Win Serv 2008 so 8 I believe. I was looking at the code as the problem when it's probably the browser

Comment: it might just be that the version of IE on the server is too old to support fullCalendar or the associated libraries. What version of IE is it?